# Do Super Mutants Sleep?

Tags: fallout-series

I've seen beds in super mutant outposts in Fallout 3/NV/4, but never seen a mutant occupying one.  Is this simply because nobody wanted to give them the necessary animations and scripting, or is there an in-story reason they don't sleep, possibly explained in Fallout 1/2?

Answer (score 2):

There is no "real" reason why super mutants never sleep. However, this might be caused by the [F.E.V](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Forced_Evolutionary_Virus) which infected them. One of it effects is that cells regenerate in such a high rate that they can't die a natural death. So I suppose - I just suppose - that the F.E.V is altering them in such a way that they don't have to sleep.